# Why ViewPager doesn't scroll inside CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**What im trying to do?**

Hello, I am trying to develop the view of a user profile in my Android application, for this I am using a CoordinatorLayout, in it, I am introducing a RecyclerView as a scrolleable element.

**My actual problem**

The problem is that although my RecyclerView activates the CoordinatorLayout when it is scrolled, if in each ViewHolder within my RecyclerView I add a ViewPager and try to scroll from it  my CoordinatorLayout doesn't work.

**What have I tried before?**

At the beginning my RecyclerView was embedded in a fragment, which I thought to reuse in several views but seeing that it did not work I simplified it by taking my RecyclerView out of the fragment and adding it to my CoordinatorLayout as its direct child.

Some time later after reading various articles on StackOverflow I tried wrapping my RecyclerView with a NestedScrollView but that didn't work either.

Coordinator Layout with nested Recycler View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CoordinatorQuestion.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.CoordinatorQuestion.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#673AB7"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".ScrollingActivity" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Post View Holder inside Recycler View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="40dp">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#9C27B0"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Media View Holder inside ViewPager2 (If you try to scroll pressing the image, CoordinatorLayout does not move):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
```

**Some util info**

Here is a video in which I visually show my problem: https://github.com/RafaelAmoMoralDev/CoordinatorQuestion/blob/main/coordinatorquestion.mp4?raw=true

And here is the repository in which if you wish you can download a small project in which to see a sample code of my problem: https://github.com/RafaelAmoMoralDev/CoordinatorQuestion

**¡Thanks in advance!**

Comment: No one would answer your question. Please post your code here and save people the stress of following unnecessary links to GitHub repos. And preferable to attach a photo instead of a video to your question and it should be on stackoverflow.

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment, I think that attaching a photo in this case does not have any relevance because you cant see the behaviour of the CoordinatorLayout scroll in a photo. Talking about write  code in the body of the question it's a nice idea and i'm going to do that but I think that cloning a minimal repo of the issue could cost 5 minutes of your time and it could give you the exactly behaviour.

Comment: Am not sure anybody here would want to clone your repo at all. Just post the code relating to the question here. Like the ViewPager and Coordinator code and then the XML layout file.

Comment: I just updated my question @Noah. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I clicked the video to understand your problem but the link is broken

Comment: I just check the link and it works, it should download a .MP4 file, check in your downloads.